# RegEx match string but not if string comes after

Tags: regex

I'm doing a find/replace and but I have already made a few changes the slow way. I want to use regex to replace the rest but make sure I don't replace ones I've already done. So, I need it to match 1 but not 2. The end result will be replacing all instances that look like 1 with 2. The -icon can be anything

```
1: <span class="glyphicons icon">
2: <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-icon">
```

More examples:

```
<span class="glyphicons hand">
<span class="glyphicons flower">
<span class="glyphicons bucket">
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-stone_head">
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-decapitated-corpse">
```

I need to replace the first 3 examples but not the last 2. The application is quite large so I'd really like to be able to do this with one 'replace all'.

Comment: do you mean you want to find "icon" and replace it with "glyphicons-icon" unless it glyphicons- already precedes icon? or specifcally the class that exists before it? what application or language is actually doing the replacement?

Comment: It's not language specific. It's for Visual Studio 2015 Find/Replace. It lets you use RegEx. I need to replace all the classes that are just "glyphicons icon" (where 'icon' can be any word) with "glyphicons glyphicons-icon" but NOT where I've already done it.

Comment: I do because the 'icon' can be anything.

Comment: does it allow for negative lookaheads? try `"glyphicons\s+(?!glyphicons)([^"]*)"` and then replace with "glyphicons glyphicons-$1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `icon` can be any word, I'd try replacing `glyphicons\s([A-Za-z]+)"` by `glyphicons glyphicons-$1"`.

Comment: Right but the actual term 'icon' is a placeholder. It could be anything.

Comment: Changed to consider `icon` just a case of any word.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @sinrise - ah, the ending " was key here... although, it wouldn't work with an example like `<span class="glyphicons decapitated-corpse">`

Comment: @smerny - this solution was assuming icon would be a word, if it had dashes then it would need negative lookahead, something like `glyphicons\s(?!glyphicons)([A-Za-z-]+)"`

Comment: i brought this up because there is a changed example of decapitated-corpse as well as one which would require underscore in the character group

Comment: Thanks that's a useful addition.